# What is the regular expression to match characters until it reaches certain characters?

Tags: python, regex

What is the regular expression to match characters until it reaches certain characters?

Below is a string I want to match the first 4 rows of ABCDEFG until I reach END.

```
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
END
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
END
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
END
```

Comment: `.*?END` ? ..................

Comment: .*END only matches the END characters and not everything before it..

Comment: In fact it matches *both*. You can use capture groups if you want to extract the part before

Comment: this won't need a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print re.findall(r"^[\s\S]*?(?=\nEND\b)",test_str)
```

This simple regex will fetch you first `4` rows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regex.

```
for line in f:
    if  line.strip() != 'END':
        print(line)
    else:
        break
```

Example:

```
l = ['sds', 'sd', 'END', 'df', 'END']
for line in l:
    if  line.strip() != 'END':
        print(line)
    else:
        break
```

output:

```
sds
sd
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you're wanting to use regex here? Something like this should suffice given the requirements you've listed:

```
try:
    data[:data.index('END')]
except ValueError:
    # handle END not found
```